# Howto Create Recommendations with a Incremental SVD Recommender System

Tags: recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering, svd, knn

I am testing a recommendation system that is built according to Simon Funk's algorithm.
(written by Timely Dev. http://www.timelydevelopment.com/demos/NetflixPrize.aspx)

The problem is, all Incremental SVD algorithms try to predict the rating for user_id and movie_id. But in a real system, this should produce a list of new items to the active user.
I see that some people used kNN after Incremental SVD, but if I don't miss something, I lose all the performance gain if I use kNN after creating the model by Incremental SVD.

Anyone has any experience with Incremental SVD/Simon Funk method, and tell me how to produce list of new recommended items?

Answer (score 1):

The way to produce recommended movies:

1. Take a list of movies that hasn't been viewed
2. Multiply their feature vector by the user's feature vector.
3. Sort descending by the result and take the top movies.

For the theory: pretend there are only two dimensions (comedy and drama). If I love comedies, but hate dramas, my feature vector is `[1.0, 0.0]`. If you compare me against the following movies:

```
Comedy:  [1.0, 0.0] x [1.0, 0.0] = 1
Dramedy: [0.5, 0.5] x [1.0, 0.0] = 0.5
Drama:   [0.0, 1.0] x [1.0, 0,0] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Python code based on Yelp Netflix code. If you install Numba it will go at C speeds.

data_loader.py

```
import os
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

class DataLoader:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def create_review_matrix(file_path):
        data = np.array([[int(tok) for tok in line.split('\t')[:3]]
                         for line in open(file_path)])

        ij = data[:, :2]
        ij -= 1
        values = data[:, 2]
        review_matrix = sparse.csc_matrix((values, ij.T)).astype(float)
        return review_matrix

movielens_file_path = '%s/Downloads/ml-100k/u1.base' % os.environ['HOME']

my_reviews = DataLoader.create_review_matrix(movielens_file_path)

user_reviews = my_reviews[8]
user_reviews = user_reviews.toarray().ravel()
user_rated_movies,  = np.where(user_reviews > 0)
user_ratings = user_reviews[user_rated_movies]

movie_reviews = my_reviews[:, 201]
movie_reviews = movie_reviews.toarray().ravel()
movie_rated_users,  = np.where(movie_reviews > 0)
movie_ratings = movie_reviews[movie_rated_users]

user_pseudo_average_ratings = {}
user_pseudo_average_ratings[8] = np.mean(user_ratings)
user_pseudo_average_ratings[9] = np.mean(user_ratings)
user_pseudo_average_ratings[10] = np.mean(user_ratings)
users, movies = my_reviews.nonzero()

users_matrix = np.empty((3, 3))
users_matrix[:] = 0.1

movies_matrix = np.empty((3, 3))
movies_matrix[:] = 0.1

result = users_matrix[0] * movies_matrix[0]
otro = movies_matrix[:, 2]
otro[2] = 8
```

funk.py

```
# Requires Movielens 100k data 
import numpy as np, time, sys
from data_loader import DataLoader
from numba import jit
import os

def get_user_ratings(user_id, review_matrix):
    """
    Returns a numpy array with the ratings that user_id has made

    :rtype : numpy array
    :param user_id: the id of the user
    :return: a numpy array with the ratings that user_id has made
    """
    user_reviews = review_matrix[user_id]
    user_reviews = user_reviews.toarray().ravel()
    user_rated_movies, = np.where(user_reviews > 0)
    user_ratings = user_reviews[user_rated_movies]
    return user_ratings

def get_movie_ratings(movie_id, review_matrix):
    """
    Returns a numpy array with the ratings that movie_id has received

    :rtype : numpy array
    :param movie_id: the id of the movie
    :return: a numpy array with the ratings that movie_id has received
    """
    movie_reviews = review_matrix[:, movie_id]
    movie_reviews = movie_reviews.toarray().ravel()
    movie_rated_users, = np.where(movie_reviews > 0)
    movie_ratings = movie_reviews[movie_rated_users]
    return movie_ratings

def create_user_feature_matrix(review_matrix, NUM_FEATURES, FEATURE_INIT_VALUE):
    """
    Creates a user feature matrix of size NUM_FEATURES X NUM_USERS
    with all cells initialized to FEATURE_INIT_VALUE

    :rtype : numpy matrix
    :return: a matrix of size NUM_FEATURES X NUM_USERS
    with all cells initialized to FEATURE_INIT_VALUE
    """
    num_users = review_matrix.shape[0]
    user_feature_matrix = np.empty((NUM_FEATURES, num_users))
    user_feature_matrix[:] = FEATURE_INIT_VALUE
    return user_feature_matrix

def create_movie_feature_matrix(review_matrix, NUM_FEATURES, FEATURE_INIT_VALUE):
    """
    Creates a user feature matrix of size NUM_FEATURES X NUM_MOVIES
    with all cells initialized to FEATURE_INIT_VALUE

    :rtype : numpy matrix
    :return: a matrix of size NUM_FEATURES X NUM_MOVIES
    with all cells initialized to FEATURE_INIT_VALUE
    """
    num_movies = review_matrix.shape[1]
    movie_feature_matrix = np.empty((NUM_FEATURES, num_movies))
    movie_feature_matrix[:] = FEATURE_INIT_VALUE
    return movie_feature_matrix

@jit(nopython=True)
def predict_rating(user_id, movie_id, user_feature_matrix, movie_feature_matrix):
    """
    Makes a prediction of the rating that user_id will give to movie_id if
    he/she sees it

    :rtype : float
    :param user_id: the id of the user
    :param movie_id: the id of the movie
    :return: a float in the range [1, 5] with the predicted rating for
    movie_id by user_id
    """
    rating = 1.
    for f in range(user_feature_matrix.shape[0]):
        rating += user_feature_matrix[f, user_id] * movie_feature_matrix[f, movie_id]

    # We trim the ratings in case they go above or below the stars range
    if rating > 5: rating = 5
    elif rating < 1: rating = 1
    return rating

@jit(nopython=True)
def sgd_inner(feature, A_row, A_col, A_data, user_feature_matrix, movie_feature_matrix, NUM_FEATURES):
    K = 0.015
    LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
    squared_error = 0
    for k in range(len(A_data)):
        user_id = A_row[k]
        movie_id = A_col[k]
        rating = A_data[k]
        p = predict_rating(user_id, movie_id, user_feature_matrix, movie_feature_matrix)
        err = rating - p

        squared_error += err ** 2

        user_feature_value = user_feature_matrix[feature, user_id]
        movie_feature_value = movie_feature_matrix[feature, movie_id]
        #for j in range(NUM_FEATURES):
        user_feature_matrix[feature, user_id] += \
            LEARNING_RATE * (err * movie_feature_value - K * user_feature_value)
        movie_feature_matrix[feature, movie_id] += \
            LEARNING_RATE * (err * user_feature_value - K * movie_feature_value)

    return squared_error

def calculate_features(A_row, A_col, A_data, user_feature_matrix, movie_feature_matrix, NUM_FEATURES):
    """
    Iterates through all the ratings in search for the best features that
    minimize the error between the predictions and the real ratings.
    This is the main function in Simon Funk SVD algorithm

    :rtype : void
    """
    MIN_IMPROVEMENT = 0.0001
    MIN_ITERATIONS = 100
    rmse = 0
    last_rmse = 0
    print len(A_data)
    num_ratings = len(A_data)
    for feature in xrange(NUM_FEATURES):
        iter = 0
        while (iter < MIN_ITERATIONS) or  (rmse < last_rmse - MIN_IMPROVEMENT):
            last_rmse = rmse
            squared_error = sgd_inner(feature, A_row, A_col, A_data, user_feature_matrix, movie_feature_matrix, NUM_FEATURES)
            rmse = (squared_error / num_ratings) ** 0.5
            iter += 1
        print ('Squared error = %f' % squared_error)
        print ('RMSE = %f' % rmse)
        print ('Feature = %d' % feature)
    return last_rmse


LAMBDA = 0.02
FEATURE_INIT_VALUE = 0.1
NUM_FEATURES = 20

movielens_file_path = '%s/Downloads/ml-100k/u1.base' % os.environ['HOME']

A = DataLoader.create_review_matrix(movielens_file_path)
from scipy.io import mmread, mmwrite
mmwrite('./data/A', A)

user_feature_matrix = create_user_feature_matrix(A, NUM_FEATURES, FEATURE_INIT_VALUE)
movie_feature_matrix = create_movie_feature_matrix(A, NUM_FEATURES, FEATURE_INIT_VALUE)

users, movies = A.nonzero()
A = A.tocoo()

rmse = calculate_features(A.row, A.col, A.data, user_feature_matrix, movie_feature_matrix, NUM_FEATURES )
print 'rmse', rmse
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a big question, as there are many recommender approaches that I think could be called "incremental SVD". To answer your specific question: kNN is run on the projected item space, not the original space, so should be quite fast.

Comment: Actually I tried to reduce the space by mentioning it is Simon Funk's algorithm and specifying the related c++ source code. If you are familiar with that algorithm, Funk uses features instead of all matrix. My initial thought is, kNN can be used on users*k (where k is the feature number, say 2), but this still may cost a bit, think about millions of users.

Comment: what I tried to say is, lets say I have 1M*50k matrix after matrix factorization, creating similarities and recommending new items for an active user would cost: finding cosine similarities in 1M users for 2 features, then finding new items in k top similar users. This is what I thought and wonder if there is a better/efficient way to do that.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was describing in my answer: you operate in the reduced (projected) space. You are describing a user-based recommender based on the user-feature matrix, which is valid.

Comment: Thank you Sean for confirming. 
After a quick implementation and test, User size: ~2K, features: 2..8, for an active user, over 1K other users have above 0.99 similarity. (used cosine-based and different k sizes)
I don't think it is normal, since users are not that much identical. Using Funk's method, first features are not trained well (according to RMSE), so I suspect the under-trained first features. Any idea?

Comment: Your projection may be buggy then, might check the quality of the reconstruction of the original matrix. If you're not using a centered cosine measure then you will get a bunch of similarities near 1 if your data is all positive and large.

Comment: I don't think the projection is the problem cause I run several MovieLens tests and RMSE are in the same range all other people (who test for netflix or academic paper) But your second point might be true, cause I have nearly all positive data (around 5) and over 200K data

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have n users and m items. After incremental SVD you have k trained features. To get the new items for a given user multiply the 1xk user feature vector and the kxm item feature matrix together. You end up with the m ratings for each item for that user. Then just sort them, remove ones they have already seen, and show some number of new ones.